# InfluxDB write performance statistics with sensu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel, influxdb, sensu

We are writing cluster performance metric collected using Sensu to influxDB on RHEL VM(16GB). I want to collect the write rates for the influxd process per second issued by it. My device location is /dev/vda1 and file location /var/lib/influxDB/data.

The problem:
There is a substantial delay between the data collection time from sensu and the time to which data is written to the InfluxDB. We suspect the disk IO performance of influx may be bottleneck but do not have concrete data to support the claim.

Tried things:
I have tried iostat, iotop and a bunch of other ways.
Using iotop influxd process shows write rate of 35kb/s average which I am sure is far less for the load we have. (I suspect it is NOT showing me the VM stats but the physical machine stats?)

Question: 
1. Is there is any other way I can collect the correct write rate metric for influxd process?
2. Has someone else faces similar issue with sensu and InfluxDB? how did yo solve it?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK Collectd can directly interface with InfluxDB. Any particular reason for using Sensu in between?

Comment: Needed a scalable, configurable monitoring pipeline for the cluster. choice to collect specific metrics from certain types, frequency of run and a few other factors led to sensu.FYI- This is on Openstack cluster

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `_internal` Influx database. It stores query times, disk usage, writes/reads, measurements, series cardinality and so on.

You could also install Telegraf on the data nodes and get disk IO, disk, CPU, network, memory and so on from the `system.inputs` section of Telegraf.